# Slow training on CPU and GPU in a small network (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, custom-training

Here is the original [script](https://github.com/marload/DeepRL-TensorFlow2/blob/master/DQN/DQN_Discrete.py) I'm trying to run on both CPU and GPU, I'm expecting a much faster training on GPU however it's taking almost the same time. I made the following modification to `main()`(the first 4 lines) because the original script does not activate / use the GPU. Suggestions ... ?

```
def main():
    physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if len(physical_devices) > 0:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
        print('GPU activated')
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    agent = Agent(env)
    agent.train(max_episodes=1000)
```

**Update:**

wandb's [report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fgn7tlm6HBUyZIcPelVjxNz_RWvY7QU_/view?usp=sharing) shows 0% GPU utilization which confirms that there is a problem

Full code in question which is not mine and belongs to this [repository](https://github.com/marload/DeepRL-TensorFlow2):

```
import wandb
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import gym
import argparse
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import random

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
wandb.init(name='DQN', project="deep-rl-tf2")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.95)
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.005)
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=32)
parser.add_argument('--eps', type=float, default=1.0)
parser.add_argument('--eps_decay', type=float, default=0.995)
parser.add_argument('--eps_min', type=float, default=0.01)

args = parser.parse_args()

class ReplayBuffer:
    def __init__(self, capacity=10000):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=capacity)
    
    def put(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.buffer.append([state, action, reward, next_state, done])
    
    def sample(self):
        sample = random.sample(self.buffer, args.batch_size)
        states, actions, rewards, next_states, done = map(np.asarray, zip(*sample))
        states = np.array(states).reshape(args.batch_size, -1)
        next_states = np.array(next_states).reshape(args.batch_size, -1)
        return states, actions, rewards, next_states, done
    
    def size(self):
        return len(self.buffer)

class ActionStateModel:
    def __init__(self, state_dim, aciton_dim):
        self.state_dim  = state_dim
        self.action_dim = aciton_dim
        self.epsilon = args.eps
        
        self.model = self.create_model()
    
    def create_model(self):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            Input((self.state_dim,)),
            Dense(32, activation='relu'),
            Dense(16, activation='relu'),
            Dense(self.action_dim)
        ])
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(args.lr))
        return model
    
    def predict(self, state):
        return self.model.predict(state)
    
    def get_action(self, state):
        state = np.reshape(state, [1, self.state_dim])
        self.epsilon *= args.eps_decay
        self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon, args.eps_min)
        q_value = self.predict(state)[0]
        if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
            return random.randint(0, self.action_dim-1)
        return np.argmax(q_value)

    def train(self, states, targets):
        self.model.fit(states, targets, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.state_dim = self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_dim = self.env.action_space.n

        self.model = ActionStateModel(self.state_dim, self.action_dim)
        self.target_model = ActionStateModel(self.state_dim, self.action_dim)
        self.target_update()

        self.buffer = ReplayBuffer()

    def target_update(self):
        weights = self.model.model.get_weights()
        self.target_model.model.set_weights(weights)
    
    def replay(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            states, actions, rewards, next_states, done = self.buffer.sample()
            targets = self.target_model.predict(states)
            next_q_values = self.target_model.predict(next_states).max(axis=1)
            targets[range(args.batch_size), actions] = rewards + (1-done) * next_q_values * args.gamma
            self.model.train(states, targets)
    
    def train(self, max_episodes=1000):
        for ep in range(max_episodes):
            done, total_reward = False, 0
            state = self.env.reset()
            while not done:
                action = self.model.get_action(state)
                next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
                self.buffer.put(state, action, reward*0.01, next_state, done)
                total_reward += reward
                state = next_state
            if self.buffer.size() >= args.batch_size:
                self.replay()
            self.target_update()
            print('EP{} EpisodeReward={}'.format(ep, total_reward))
            wandb.log({'Reward': total_reward})


def main():
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    agent = Agent(env)
    agent.train(max_episodes=1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How long in time is the GPU taking vs the CPU?

Comment: @Robert Young I did not calculate the exact time since it might run for hours, I just run it on my 2015 i5 mbp and I then run it on google colab, and by comparing the local version vs colab version, each screen shows progression with almost the same speed

Comment: Please don't link to off-site code. Who knows where the linked repository (or GitHub, for that matter!) is when someone reads this question 5 (or 10, or 20) years down the line.

Answer (score 1):

I very much suspect that I/O operations are taking up almost everything (particularly with your self-implemented replay-buffer). To check this I suggest using the [TF-profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#install_the_profiler_and_gpu_prerequisites); to do this, try one of [these](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#profiling_apis) approaches. There are also some very useful videos on Youtube on how to use the profiler if you have any further problems.

As to possible optimizations to speed up your code I would higly recommend moving to the TF-Agents framework where agents, replay buffers, ecc. are already pre-implemented in an efficient way. It's a bit of a learning curve to get to know it, but it's well worth it for RL

Comment: It's not my code, and you're right, the IO operations are definitely taking most of the time but 0% GPU utilization? it's somewhat unexpected. I'm using this code and several other versions to familiarize myself with DRL algorithms(with as minimal implementation details to worry about as possible) as there is no proper courses available for this topic as it is relatively new. Once I understand the inner working of different DRL algorithms, I might switch to tensorflow agents if they are flexible enough to customize / use asynchronously with other agents. I'll check the tf-profiler, thanks.