# tensorflow 0% GPU utilization despite manual activation

Tags: python, tensorflow, custom-training

This is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196943/slow-training-on-cpu-and-gpu-in-a-small-network-tensorflow) in which I indicated CPU and GPU slow training performance. I did another test run on google colab and used [wandb](https://github.com/wandb/client) to monitor the training and show CPU, GPU utilization and several other metrics, it shows 0% GPU utilization which confirms the GPU is not in use and tensorflow is just ignoring the activation or I don't know.

I activate the GPU using (`tf` 2.3.1):

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Graphs within a few minutes of training:

[image: report-1]

[image: report-2]

[image: report-3]

Comment: Just in case have you checked in logs that gpu actually found by tensorflow?

Comment: yes, the GPU is present in all the recent trial runs, I'm starting to believe that this is not more of an implementation problem and less of a tensorflow problem.

Comment: @bullseye It's hard to judge without actual runnable code sample. Could you share the colab notebook (or its copy)?

Comment: @tornikeo you may use this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/amahendrakar/e09b444c63660052f3f679a954cdd587/45546.ipynb)

Comment: @bullseye The notebook runs into an error as soon as the training script starts executing. Maybe that's why GPU usage is not showing up. you might wanna check the notebook for errors